# Why do 4 circles cover the surface of a sphere?

Tags: geometry, intuition

Is there a geometric explanation for why a sphere has surface area $4 \pi r^2$ ?
Ie equal to 4 times its cross-section (a circle of radius r).

Comment: This link does not give a full answer, but it may help a little: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_the_Sphere_and_Cylinder

Comment: I would add to the comment of Eivind: the map from the cylinder to the sphere given by orthogonal projection from the axis  is area-preserving. It's a nice exercise to show that it shrinks horizontal infinitesimal distances by the same factor as it expands  vertical infinitesimal distances.

Comment: What does cross-section mean here?

Comment: Here's a cute interpretation of the problem: On a [spherical wedge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_wedge) of angle 90°, the curved outer surface has the same surface area as the two planar semicircular ends put together. One can think of these as two non-minimal surfaces on the same boundary curve. Why do they have the same area? (Of course, the answer may just be that it is a coincidence.)

Comment: See here http://mathcentral.uregina.ca/QQ/database/QQ.09.99/wilkie1.html

Comment: A very old question, but perhaps it can be explained through visual aid here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GNcFjFmqEc8

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let $Z$ be a cylinder of height $2r$ touching the sphere $S_r$ along the equator $\theta=0$. Consider now a thin plate orthogonal to the $z$-axis having a thickness  $\Delta z\ll r$. It intersects  $S_r$ at a certain geographical latitude $\theta$ in a nonplanar annulus of radius $\rho= r\cos\theta$ and width $\Delta s=\Delta z/\cos\theta$, and it intersects $Z$ in a cylinder of height $\Delta z$. Both these "annuli" have the same area $2\pi r \Delta z$. As this is true for any such plate it follows that the total area of the sphere $S_r$ is the same as the total area of $Z$, namely $4\pi r^2$.

Comment: A "plate" here just means a very short cylinder, right?

Comment: @LarsH: That's right.

Answer (score 8):

One geometric explanation is that $4\pi r^2$ is the derivative of $\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3$, the volume of the ball with radius $r$, with respect to $r$. This is because if you enlarge $r$ a little bit, the volume of the ball will change by its surface times the small enlargement of $r$.

So why is the volume of the full ball $\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3$? By slicing the ball into disks, using Pythagoras, you get that its volume is
$$
\int_{-r}^r \pi (r^2-x^2)\mathrm{d}x
$$
which is indeed $\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3$.

Comment: Is this true for all manifolds, dV/dr=S?, where V is the n-volume and S is the n-1-surface and r is the distance from a point in the interior to the surcface ?

Comment: @solomoan: I think you will have trouble defining "the distance from a point in the interior to the surface" for a general manifold with boundary. I don't see how to generalise the result in a meaningful way to general manifolds.

Comment: @solomoan: If $$f: B\to{\mathbb R}^3, \quad (u,v)\mapsto f(u,v)$$ produces a surface $S$ with unit normal $n(u,v)$ then $$x: \ B\times[0,\epsilon]\ \to\  {\mathbb R}^3, \quad (u,v,t)\mapsto f(u,v)+ t n(u,v)$$ produces a plate of thickness $\epsilon$. You can compute the volume $V(\epsilon)$ of this plate by means of the Jacobian of $x$, and calculating the limit $$\lim_{\epsilon\to0}{V(\epsilon)\over\epsilon}$$  you get the formula for the surface area $\omega(S)$.

Answer (score 2):

In the first step consider a hemi-sphere radius $R$ and its enveloping cylinder at the equator of sphere of length/ height $R$, $\phi=p=$ slope and $dz$ is differential length along axis as shown.

[image]

$$ d(Area)= 2\pi r dl,\; \text{since}(\cos \phi = r/R  = dz/dl) , d (Area) = 2 \pi R dz\;; $$

Integrating for an axial length for sphere

$$\Delta Area= 2 \pi R \Delta z $$

Next step consider the cylinder from which this segment projects between same parallels. Directly its prismatic area is

$$\Delta Area =   2 \pi R \cdot \Delta z $$

The difference areas $abfe$ and $dcfe$ are equal.

For the full sphere/tangent cylinder accordingly the same area.

It was became known from Archimedes's time , he last-wished it to be inscribed on his tombstone when attacked by soldiers.